# Cant display todo items in simple React app

Tags: reactjs, jsx

i am new to React and i want to build a simple todo app.
I have made two components one to make a todo item and one for display it.

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import TodoList from "./TodoList";

function TodoForm() {
  const inputItem = useRef();
  const [itemExist, setItem] = useState(false);

  function submitHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setItem(true);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <label>
          Todo-item
          <input name="item" type="text" ref={inputItem}></input>
        </label>
        <input type="submit"></input>
      </form>
      {itemExist && <TodoList item={inputItem.current.value}></TodoList>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default TodoForm;
```

Component for display the doto items

```
function TodoList(props) {
    return (
        <ul>
            <li>{props.item }</li>
        </ul>
  );
}

export default TodoList;
```

When i submit the first item i cant add other item.
I have tried to to change the itemExist to false under the
     `{itemExist && <TodoList item={inputItem.current.value}></TodoList>}`
but error occurs. Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders

Comment: Its cause you are setting 1 item instead of using an array with the items in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function TodoForm() {
  const inputItem = useRef();
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  function submitHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let newTodos = [...todos, { inputItem.current.value }];
    setTodos(newTodos);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <label>
          Todo-item
          <input name="item" type="text" ref={inputItem}></input>
        </label>
        <input type="submit"></input>
      </form>
      {todos.map((todo, i) => {
return(
<TodoList key={`todo_${i}`} item={todo}></TodoList>
)
})}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank Chad. It works. But im not sure how it works. Every time  add a todo re-renders all the list? Two return statements in TodoForm?

Comment: @ΔημήτρηςΤσιδοδήμος Its pushing a todo item to the useState instead of setting 1 item, and then for each item inside that array it renders a `TodoList` component with that item

Comment: What i cant understand is two return functions in same component one below the other.

Comment: Where? send the code you're referring to

Comment: Sorry, i have made a mistake. The last return is from function parameter inside map.